# I need help getting UNION to behave with JOIN

Tags: t-sql, join, union

I'm trying to generate a report that gives me data from 3 different tables. I used a UNION first, now I need to get one column from the last table. I tried a JOIN but it breaks my code.

Here's what I want:
Select document number,  patient full name (in one column), patient account number where patient zip = ‘45142’ then Add location of claim (trans or history) after you get the first part.

This is the bulk of my data

```
(SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER, TRANS_TYPE, PATIENT_LAST_NAME + ',  ' + PATIENT_FIRST_NAME AS NAME,PATIENT_ZIP 
   FROM  HCFA_M
  WHERE patient_zip like '45142%') 

UNION

(SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER, TRANS_TYPE, PATIENT_LAST_NAME + ',  ' + PATIENT_FIRST_NAME AS NAME,PATIENT_ZIP 
   FROM UB_M 
  WHERE patient_zip like '45142%')

  ORDER BY NAME asc, TRANS_TYPE
```

The table I need the last colum from is

```
SELECT LOCATION
  FROM DOCUMENT_M
```

Comment: Show the join that failed and what conditions to join on.

Answer (score 0):

Going to guess on join condition

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER, TRANS_TYPE, PATIENT_LAST_NAME + ',  ' + PATIENT_FIRST_NAME AS NAME,PATIENT_ZIP, LOCATION  
   FROM HCFA_M
   JOIN DOCUMENT_M 
     ON DOCUMENT_M.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = HCFA_M.DOCUMENT_NUMBER
  WHERE patient_zip like '45142%'
```